# Converting XML feed to JSON preserving the itunes:image data

Tags: javascript, google-api, winjs

I need to convert a podcast feed XML to JSON. Today I use the Google API to convert my feed to JSON, using the sentence:

```
var jsonUrl = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json&num=999&q="
              + encodeURIComponent(xmlUrl);

WinJS.xhr({ url: jsonUrl, responseType: document }).done( ... )
```

This works, but I'm also interested in the < itunes:image ... > data that these feeds have most of the time, but using the Google APIs it just give me Atom and RSS elements and ignore the itunes' ones.

There's any way I can modify my Google call or even use some javascript inside my code, reading the XML and converting it myself, to get a standard RSS Json plus the itunes image info?

Answer (score 0):

Is [`jQuery.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) what you are looking for?